# How to create a form with foreign key django

Tags: python, django, valueerror

I'm working on a Django project and getting the Value error below.
I think the problem is in the category field because if I will comment it in new.html, it adding a listing without the problem. However, I can't find where is the error:

*ValueError at /new
The view auctions.views.add_listing didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*

This is my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=24, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField()
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, default=None, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def add_listing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print('FORM CREATED')
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            print('FORM IS VALID')
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            new_listing = form.save(commit=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(listing, args={new_listing.pk,}))
        else:
            pass
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/new.html",{
            'category':Category.objects.all()
        })
```

new.html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="listing" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <input type="text" name="title">

    <h4>Choose category</h4>

    <select name="category" id="">
        {% for type in category %}
        <option value="{{ type }}" name="category">{{ type }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>


    <h4>Description</h4>
    <input type="text" name="description">

    <h4>Price</h4>
    <input type="number" name="price">

    <h4>Photo</h4>
    <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="photo" id="file">

    <!-- <p>Or provide URL of image</p>
    <input type="text" name="image_url"/> -->

    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>

</form>
```

forms.py:

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = [
            "title",
            "description",
            "price",
            "photo",
            "category"
        ]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(
            name = self.cleaned_data['category']
        )
        self.cleaned_data['category'] = category.id
        return super(ListingForm, self).save(commit)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: could you please add your `forms.py`?

Comment: are you sure about this: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(listing, args={new_listing.pk,}))`? I do not see any `listing` variable in the view

Comment: You wrote in your `add_listing` view, `if form.is_valid(): ... else: pass`. Your form is not valid, then you enter in the else block that also don't return any httpresponse object. You must redirect to the same view instead (`... else: return redirect('.')`

Comment: @Christophe, I added forms. Regarding listing variable, I pass it to redirect to the listing page

Comment: @Rvector, I added ```else:pass``` just to troubleshoot. If I will delete it, the error would be still there

Comment: yes you pass it... but it's never defined!